# Confused about increment operator in C

Tags: c, syntax, stack

I've written a program in C to create a basic stack using an array. It works as expected, but there is something I'm very confused about. On the first line of the push method, I increment the value of *top_ptr, which is a pointer to the variable top, using the syntax
`*top_ptr = *top_ptr+1`. When I try to replace this line with `*top_ptr++`, which I think is more concise and meant the same thing, I get a warning that says Wunused variable, and a segmentation fault error when running it. The warning message from my terminal, word for word, is

```
warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
*top_ptr++;
^~~~~~~~~~
```

and my exact error message from the terminal is:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  ./stacks/arrayi
```

When I run the program with the current program, my output is what I expect: `1 2 3 %`

My code is below. Again, the line I'm confused about is the first line of the push method, which is line 17. If you answer this, then thank you for your time and consideration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 101

void push(int *, int *, int);
void print(int *, int *);
int main() {
  int top = -1;
  int *top_ptr = &top;
  int arr[MAX_SIZE];
  push(arr, top_ptr, 1);
  push(arr, top_ptr, 2);
  push(arr, top_ptr, 3);
  print(arr, top_ptr);
}

void push(int *array, int *top_ptr, int x) {
  *top_ptr = *top_ptr + 1;
  array[*top_ptr] = x;
}

void print(int *array, int *top_ptr) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= *top_ptr; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also do: `*top_ptr += 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*top_ptr++` is `*(top_ptr++)`, which is wrong because it changes `top_ptr`, which is not what you want to do.

You want `(*top_ptr)++`.

The compiler warns you the expression result is unused because, after `(top_ptr++)`, the `*` fetches the value that `(top_ptr++)` points to, but nothing is done with that value. That is suspicious, so the compiler warns you you have told it to get a value but not to do anything with it.

In contrast, with `(*top_ptr)++`, it does not warn you because the `++` modifies the thing that `(*top_ptr)` points to, so the expression finishes with a useful action.

Comment: This was concise and helpful. Worked like a charm. Now I know to look for it in the future.  Thank you for not only the answer, but also the explanation Eric (:

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing

```
(*top_ptr)++;
```

that bracket is important. if u don't give the bracket then basically it'll be executed like

```
*(top_ptr++);
```

i.e. at first the pointer top_ptr will be incremented and then it'd be deferenced. that's why it's giving you segmentation fault. 
(and the value pointed by top_ptr won't be incremented)